# Is it OK to shut off the A/C at the breaker?

Tags: hvac

My A/C continues to run even after the thermostat says it should shut off. Can I shut off the A/C by tripping the circuit breaker until it can be looked at?  Is there any safety issue with doing this?

Comment: If you figure it to be a fault then yes. Shut it off. But it most likely could be normal operation as AC needs run a bit after turning off to decompress gasses.. cool down.. de pressurise or whatever it needs to do.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is ok to shut it off at the breaker until you can have someone qualified look at it.  This is the easiest, safest option for you.  It will ensure that everything is safely shut off, including the compressor, evaporator, and any other components that your particular A/C unit has.